# Error at creating GIF Image with ImageMagick: too many exceptions and blinking problem

Tags: linux, image, terminal, imagemagick, gif

I have a directory with a lot of png files with the next structure:

```
image1.png
image2.png
...
image3372.png
```

I am trying to create a GIF image with *ImageMagick*, so in a Terminal I am typing:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
convert -delay 0.01 -loop 0 *.png myimage.gif
```

But I have the next errors:

```
...
convert-im6.q16: DistributedPixelCache '127.0.0.1' @ error/distribute-cache.c
/ConnectPixelCacheServer/244.
convert-im6.q16: cache resources exhausted `Image119.png' @ error/cache.c/OpenPixelCache/3984.
convert-im6.q16: too many exceptions (exception processing suspended).
```

And the GIF created is not complete:
[image]

Also, it blinks. I think it is because it is considering image18 and image180 as consecutive. How do I fix that?

I am running Ubuntu 18

Edit:
New Image generated by xenoid suggestions
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 100 frames/second is overkill. You can run with 10 frames/sec and divide the image count by 10 (or at least the standard 25 frames/sec and divide by 4).
2. `*.png` is expanded and sorted **alphabetically** by your shell,so if you want frames in their number sequence, pad the names with 0's:

```
for n in {1..3372} ; ; do mv image$n.png image$(printf "%04d" $n).png ; done
```

3. `convert` (and other IM commands) uses a memory cache and has several self-enforced limits (that you can list with IM's `identify` command):

```
>>> identify -list resource
Resource limits:
  Width: 16KP
  Height: 16KP
  List length: 18.446744EP
  Area: 128MP
  Memory: 256MiB
  Map: 512MiB
  Disk: 1GiB
  File: 768
  Thread: 8
  Throttle: 0
  Time: unlimited
```

- You can boost the limit for one run:

```
convert -limit memory 1000  ...
```

- For more permanent changes you can also edit `/etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml` and look for lines such as `<policy domain="resource" name="memory" value="256MiB"/>` and increase the necessary ones.

Comment: I had the same problem with `convert -delay 0.1 -loop 0 *.png myimage.gif`. How do I divide the Image count by ten? .. Also, I think you added and extra ; here:  `for n in {1..3372} ; ; do mv image$n.png image$(printf "%04d" $n).png ; done`

Comment: To divide by 10 only use the images that ends with the same digit:: `convert -delay 0.1 -loop 0 *1.png myimage.gif`

Comment: Great, but I still have the same error, although the image has improved dramatically (See my Edit)

Comment: See edited answer, IM put limits on resource usage this can be lifted temporarily